# Open dialog box with contents php traversed from a database using js/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am creating an image map with buttons. The buttons are created by php:

```
while($pc = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
if ($pc['Online_Status']==0){
    $class = 'workstation-offline';
}
else{
    $class = 'workstation-online';
}


echo "\r\n\t\t\t".'<button class="'.$class.'" id="'.$pc['PCID'].'" title= "'.$pc['PCID'].'>';
}
```

When the page loads, traverse.php dictates what class the button will be. In my css, the workstation-offline will be green, and red if offline. traverse.php also loads data from a database.

This is the html code:

```
<div class="image_map" style="background-image: url('image.jpg');">
    <?php 
        include("traverse.php"); 
    ?>

</div>
```

What I'd like to happen is when a button is clicked, a dialog box will open and display data about the station with the ID "pc['PCID']" in a table like:

```
<h3>"The ID of the Button"</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>IP Address</td>
        <td>pc['ipAddress']</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>MAC Address</td>
        <td>pc['macAddress']</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Other Info</td>
        <td>pc['otherInfo']</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I do that using js/jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use jquery-ui modal dialog box. (http://jqueryui.com)

You could load data on the fly like this. Here's a click handler for the buttons that will create a dialog box and then load data from a server side page  :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.workstation-online,.workstation-offline').click(function () {
        var url = "put the url to obtain info from database here";
        var dialog = $('<div style="display:none" class="loading"></div>').appendTo('body');
            dialog.dialog({
                resizable: false,
                width: 400,
                height: 300,
                modal: true,
                closeText: '',
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    // remove div with all data and events
                    dialog.remove();
                }
            });
            dialog.load(
                url,
                function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // remove the loading class
                    dialog.removeClass('loading');
                }
            );
            return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Geeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee, thanks man! The onclick function is working now! But I still don't know how to put the data to the dialog box. I'm really new to js/jquery.

Comment: You could have a php page that get the data from the database and generate the html that goes into the dialog window. Once this is done, just assign the url javascript variable in the code I'd post : var url = 'display_station_data.php?id=' + this.attr('id');

Comment: By the way, I would put the station Id in a different attribute then the Id of the button... like this :
`echo "\r\n\t\t\t".'<button class="'.$class.'" id="btn'.$pc['PCID'].'" title= "'.$pc['PCID'].'" **stationId="'.$pc['PCID'].'"** />';`
Then in the click handler, when you  construct the url, I would use `this.attr('stationId')`
(I may have a syntax error because I don't know php really much.)

Comment: I added this to my code: var url = 'traverse.php?id='pc['PCID']'';
Now, the dialog box doesn't appear anymore. Do I have to create a new php file just for the purpose of getting data from the database?

Comment: You have a javascript error. The id must be between the quotes.
**Don't use php there...** since this code is call from every buttons of different stations. `var url = 'display_station_data.php?id=' + this.attr('id');` is the way to go.

Comment: what's this? where is it from? this.attr('id');

Man, I really appreciate the effort very much! People like you are life savers. Im sorry im really a noob here. haha
What's your email address? I want to send you the files so you can better check it. :)

Comment: `this.attr('id')` is jquery code. `this` = the button that has been click. `attr` access the attributes of an element so `this.attr('id')` return the value of id attribute of the button that has been click.
No worrry! Not so long ago, I was n00b too in Jquery. :)

Comment: I'll try this one later. I need to digest all the info you gave me then I'll just post updates here. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Hey @matthieu G. Finally, I now get the purpose of the code:
var url = "put the url to obtain info from database here";
so you're concatenating the string 'display_station_data.php?id=' and the attribute 'stationId'
so the final url of what will be displayed in the dialog box is display_station_data.php?id=something
i tried getting to that url and it went well, i was able to get the php page to display the right stuff. however, nothing happens when I click the buttons.

Comment: If nothing happens, there's an error in the javascript. Check the rendered code is okay and that everything that need to be between ' ' or " " is there and that every lines finish with ;. You can post a http://jsfiddle.net/ too. I'll check it out.